# During exceptions generated KeyError: 'Id'

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

Actually, I am trying to track the image and when I click on the track image button it opens the camera but provides an exception relating to Id.

> ```
> Exception in Tkinter callback
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\pc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3078, in get_loc
> return self._engine.get_loc(key)
> File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
> File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
> File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
> File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
> KeyError: 'Id'
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\pc\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
> return self.func(*args)
> File "I:/Attendence_Project/Attendence.py", line 166, in TrackImages
> aa = df.iloc[df['Id'] == Id]['Name'].values
> File "C:\Users\pc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2688, in __getitem__
> return self._getitem_column(key)
> File "C:\Users\pc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2695, in _getitem_column
> return self._get_item_cache(key)
> File "C:\Users\pc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2489, in _get_item_cache
> values = self._data.get(item)
> File "C:\Users\pc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4115, in get
> loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
> File "C:\Users\pc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
> return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
> File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
> File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
> File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
> File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
> KeyError: 'Id'
> ```

I have saved my data in a CSV(Excel) file and images are stored in a folder.
As I have trained data(YML format) of the stored images in the folder.
Please help me out in removing this error.

````
def TrackImages():
    recognizer = cv2.face_LBPHFaceRecognizer.create()
    recognizer.read("TrainingImageLabel\Trainner.yml")
    harcascadePath = "I:\\opencv\\build\\etc\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
    faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(harcascadePath);
    df = pd.read_csv("StudentDetails\studentDetails.csv",header=0,encoding = 'unicode_escape')
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    col_names = ['Id','Name','Date','Time']
    attendence = pd.DataFrame(columns = col_names)
    while True:
        ret, im = cam.read()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.2, 5)
        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(im, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (255,0,0),2)
            Id, conf = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y+h, x:x+w])
            if (conf <50):
                ts = time.time()
                date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                timeStamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
                aa = df.iloc[df['Id'] == Id]['Name'].values      **Error generating line**
                tt = str(Id)+"-"+aa
                attendence.iloc[len(attendence)] = [Id,aa,date,timeStamp]

            else:
                Id = 'Unknown'
                tt = str(Id)
            if(conf>75):
                noOfFile = len(os.listdir("ImagesUnknown"))+1
                cv2.imwrite("ImagesUnknown\Image"+str(noOfFile)+".jpg", im[y:y+h,x:x+w])
            cv2.putText(im.str(tt), (x,y+h), font, 1,(255,255,255),2)  
        attendence= attendence.drop_duplicates(subset = ['Id'], keep='first')
        cv2.imshow('im',im)
        if (cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q')):
            break
    ts = time.time()
    date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    timeStamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    Hour,Minute,Second = timeStamp.split(":")
    fileName = "Attendence\Attendence_" +date+"_"+ Hour+"-"+Minute+"-"+Second+".csv"
    attendence.to_csv(fileName,index=False)
    cam.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    res = attendence
    message1.configure(text = res)```
````

Comment: What do you want to accomplish here? `im` is of type `numpy.ndarray`, `tt` is already of type `str`. Should be probably read: `.putText(im, tt, ...`. Read [cv2.putText](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#cv2.putText)

Comment: What object class has a `str` method?

Comment: @hpaulj Sorry, Can you please make it more clear so that I can provide you the correct details of what you are asking. ThankYou!

Comment: @stovfl Hey ThankYou so much for giving your valuable time. I am able to solve the issue through your support but now one more error has occurred, Please help me. I am editing my post please look after it.

Comment: Your edit changed the question significantly.  You should ask a new question!

Comment: @hpaulj: Read [str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str)

Comment: @StayAtOrbit: ***`KeyError: 'Id'`***: The Dataframe `self._engine` has no Column with `key=='Id'`

Comment: @stovfl, you link to a `str` class.  The OP's problem was in a `im.str(tt)` expression, which is interpreted as asking `im` for its `str` method.  That's a very different thing.

Comment: ***"That's a very different thing."***: It's a typo, should be `im, str(tt)`, but `tt` is already of type `str` therefore `str(...)` is not needed.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes I've changed the question because my earlier problem is solved and some new error occurred.

Comment: @StayAtOrbit: ***"Yes I've changed the question because my earlier problem is solved"***: This is not how it works at SO!. Revert or delete your question, ask a **new** question about your **new** Issue. Your **new** Issue is related to `pandas` therefore you have to use **new** tags as well.

Comment: @stovfl Ohkay I will as you say. And thank you so much for this support.